# ARD installing .app files

Tags: remote-desktop

I am new to ARD.  The Install interface will only accept .pkg files.  Is there a quick way to get an .app file to install instead?  Some of the applications that I need to install are pkg, and others are app types.
Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score 1):

To install .app files on remote Macs you would use the Copy button instead of the Install button.

After hitting Copy select the .app files you want on the mac(s) from the Place Items In drop down select Applications Folder.

.app files cannot technically be installed as it is just the application, which is why it can just be copied.